# SQL-DMO: You must use SQL Server 2005 management tools to connect to this server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2000

Getting an error in SQL Server 2000 Enterprise manager - Please see in the attached screenshot!

Kindly help how to overcome the issue

[image]

Comment: One screenshot is sufficient. Also note, that you can easily copy/paste the message text of a Windows message box by pressing `Cltr+C` while the message box has focus, thus not needing a screenshot at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to install the [backward compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms143706%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) package. You can [download it from here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=15748).The file is called SQLServer2005_BCxxx.msi

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to access a SQL Server 2005 instance using SQL Server 2000's Enterprise Manager, which isn't possible.
You need to install a copy of SQL Server Management Studio - the [2008 R2Express version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985) should be fine, or you can dig out the [2005 version](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=8961)

Comment: Hello, Seems you are not understand my issue properly. I'm not trying 2005/2008 instances in 2000 SQL. As David said `Backward compatibility` Package is needed for that issue/error.

Comment: That backward compatibility package is so that SQL Management Studio 2005 can fully interact with SQL 2000 instances, especially DTS packages. Your screenshot shows the SQL Server Enterprise Manager which comes with SQL Server 2000, and that it is trying to connect to an instance of SQL Express which only exists with SQL Server 2005+.

Comment: Your heading, however, mentions SQL-DMO which is covered by the compatibility package.